# I put an image in my html file but it doesn't load

Tags: html

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/muham/Desktop/HTML/Akaria.jpeg" alt="Akaria logo">
```

This is what I write on the Atom Text editor, but the image doesn't load

Comment: Did you check the developer tools console for errors? Where are you serving the page from? Are you opening it from the disk?

Comment: *image doesn't load* where it doesn't load? You load it via a webserver or how?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**img** element in your **index.html**:
`<img src="assets/images/some-picture.jpg" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

First make a folder than copy your files in it and make an image folder place all your images there and then give the right path in the image src it will work.

**like this:**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It might be possibly caused by your reference to the img source. You can left click and get the relative path  instead of absolute path and try using it which might possibly solve your issue. Also check your file name and remember that it is case sensitive- might misspell the name of the image file as well. Maybe, I am not sure on that, but using width and height attributes might also be useful, but I don't think it was the issue. Probably, your reference/file name is wrong. HMU if u need any help or if it works or not